# Why git is showing hidden files and hidden directories when I use ls command without -a option?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

My operating system is Windows 7 64-bit.

I have a folder `D:\Temp`.

Inside `D:\Temp`, I have 3 directories: `Directory1`, `Directory2` and `HiddenDirectory1`.

Inside `D:\Temp`, I have 3 files: `File1.txt`, `File2.txt` and `HiddenFile1.txt`.

`HiddenDirectory1` is a hidden directory. `HiddenFile1.txt` is a hidden file.

I open up Git Bash console and went to `D:\Temp` directory.

When I use `ls` command with no options I was supposed to see only visible items but I saw the hidden items as well:
[image]

Why the `ls` command is showing me the hidden items? I thought I will see the hidden items only when I use `ls -a` command? What went wrong?

TIA

Comment: Git Bash is a Linux-like environment. In Linux-like environments, "hidden" files are those whose names start with a `.` - unlike in Windows, which has a separate hidden flag.

Comment: oh. so Git Bash does not care if an item has a hidden flag on or off? For Git Bash both are not hidden?

Comment: Yep, Git doesn't "care" about windows file system flags.

Comment: Thanks. @Amber can you make your remark an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @ChumboChappati done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git Bash is a Linux-like environment. In Linux-like environments, "hidden" files are those whose names start with a `.` - unlike in Windows, which has a separate hidden flag.